# How to get two columns of two different tables where id = id and id= 9?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

my first query :

```
SELECT `oc_banner_image_description`.`title` 
FROM `oc_banner_image_description` 
WHERE `banner_id`=9
```

my second query:

```
SELECT `oc_banner_image`.`image` FROM `oc_banner_image` WHERE `banner_id`=9
```

how to make this two queries into single query using sql joins.

Comment: Other than with a join?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think he wants a join.

Comment: @Hogan: I know. I was being facetious.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - wow, my middle name is facetious and I didn't notice.

Answer (score 2):

Using standard join syntax would look like this :

```
SELECT `oc_banner_image_description`.`title`, `oc_banner_image`.`image`
FROM `oc_banner_image_description` 
JOIN `oc_banner_image` ON `oc_banner_image_description`.`banner_id` = `oc_banner_image`.`banner_id`
WHERE `oc_banner_image`.`banner_id`=9
```

Comment: I got below Error,                                                                                                                Error

SQL query: Documentation

SELECT `oc_banner_image_description`.`title`, `oc_banner_image`.`image`
FROM `oc_banner_image_description` 
JOIN `oc_banner_image` ON `oc_banner_image_description`.`banner_id` = `oc_banner_image`.`banner_id`
WHERE `banner_id`=9
 LIMIT 0, 25 

MySQL said: Documentation
#1052 - Column 'banner_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @Tharunkumar -- ok, that is easy to fix, fix it... make it non ambiguous.

Comment: how to to do it ? please guide me

Comment: @Tharunkumar - **hint, I edited the code above** but it is not hard to figure out... just add the table name before the ambiguous part.  Since both tables have the same value of banner_id it does not matter which one you add.

Comment: got same results as i mentioned in below code getting 25 results instead of five results

Comment: This means one of your tables has more than 1 (probably 5 each) rows for each banner_id.  There is no way for us to help you unless you tell us the whole data model -- you want help on another question then post that question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (You may need to use the single quotes a bit different than what I have)

```
SELECT `i`.`image`, `d`.`title`
FROM `oc_banner_image` as `i`, `oc_banner_image_description` as `d` 
WHERE `c.banner_id` = `i.banner_id`
and i.`banner_id`=9
```

If this is not working try this on both tables

```
select banner_id, count(banner_id) 
  from oc_banner_image 
 group by banner_id order desc;
```

This will tell you if you have multiple `banner_id`'s in the `oc_banner_image` table.

Comment: correction in your query, SELECT `i`.`image`, `d`.`title` FROM `oc_banner_image` as `i`, `oc_banner_image_description` as `d` WHERE `d`.`banner_id` = `i`.`banner_id` and `i`.`banner_id`=9 and result i got   image  title  
catalog/4.jpg  Indutrues 5
catalog/4.jpg  Industry 4
catalog/4.jpg  Industry 3
catalog/4.jpg  Industry 2
catalog/4.jpg  Industry 1
catalog/3.jpg  Indutrues 5
catalog/3.jpg  Industry 4
catalog/3.jpg  Industry 3
catalog/3.jpg  Industry 2
catalog/3.jpg  Industry 1
catalog/2.jpg  Indutrues 5
catalog/2.jpg  Industry 4
catalog/2.jpg  Industry 3
catalog/2.jpg  Industry 2
catalog/2.j

Comment: Well spotted, does it look ok now? More importantly did it help?

Comment: Nope i need only 5 rows..like catalog/5.jpg Indutrues 5, catalog/4.jpg Indutrues 4, catalog/3.jpg Indutrues3, catalog/2.jpg Indutrues 2, catalog/1.jpg Indutrues 1,

Comment: That's strange, the join on `banner_id` if unique in one of the tables should do all the filtering you need.

Comment: Am unable to add image as screenshot else i can show the results.

Comment: You have duplicates in the tables. Normally `banner_id` needs to be unique if you want to use it to link tables like this. Is one of the tables mean to have unique for every row in it `banner_id` if not then you will likely get multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`SELECT bannerDesc.title , bannerImage.image
FROM oc_banner_image_description bannerDesc join  oc_banner_image bannerImage
on bannerDesc.banner_id = bannerImage.banner_id
WHERE bannerImage.banner_id=9`